# How to hide but not disable scrollbar in JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing

I've tried something like this:

```
    getHorizontalScrollBar().setPreferredSize (new Dimension(0,0));
```

or

```
    setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

But it also disables scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TableHorizontal
{
    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        final JTable table = new JTable(10, 10);
        table.setAutoResizeMode( JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF );
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( scrollPane );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The above code is a `SSCCE`. If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem. All questions should include a `SSCCE` instead of a statement like "it doesn' work", that demonstrates exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
panLeft.setLayout(null);
panLeft.setPreferredSize(null);
panLeft.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListenerPanLeft());

scrollPaneLeft.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
scrollPaneLeft.getViewport().setBorder(null);
scrollPaneLeft.setViewportBorder(null);
scrollPaneLeft.setBorder(null);
```